# Apache Flink JobManager Unable to Find Custom Metrics Reporter

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Apache Flink version `1.13.1`

I wrote a custom metrics reporter, but the JobManager does not seem to recognise it. On startup, the JobManager shows the following warning log:

```
2021-08-25 14:54:06,243 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.ReporterSetup               [] - The reporter factory (org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka.KafkaReporterFactory) could not be found for reporter kafka. Available factories: [org.apache.flink.metrics.slf4j.Slf4jReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.datadog.DatadogHttpReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporterFactory, org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.InfluxdbReporterFactory].
2021-08-25 14:54:06,245 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl          [] - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
```

I have a folder within the Flink plugins folder called `metrics-kafka` which contains the packaged jar for the metrics reporter. I have also copied this jar to the lib folder, both of which did not work. See the configuration and code used below.

**Flink configuration file**:

```yaml
metrics.reporter.kafka.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka.KafkaReporterFactory
metrics.reporter.kafka.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka.KafkaReporter
metrics.reporter.kafka.interval: 15 SECONDS
```

**Metrics reporter factory class**:

```java
package org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka

import org.apache.flink.metrics.reporter.{InterceptInstantiationViaReflection, MetricReporter, MetricReporterFactory}
import java.util.Properties

@InterceptInstantiationViaReflection(reporterClassName = "org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka.KafkaReporter")
class KafkaReporterFactory extends MetricReporterFactory{
  override def createMetricReporter(properties: Properties): MetricReporter = {
    new KafkaReporter()
  }
}
```

**Metrics reporter class**:

```java
package org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka

import org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricConfig
import org.apache.flink.metrics.reporter.{InstantiateViaFactory, Scheduled}

@InstantiateViaFactory(factoryClassName = "org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka.KafkaReporterFactory")
class KafkaReporter extends MyAbstractReporter with Scheduled{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that I needed to add a file called `org.apache.flink.metrics.reporter.MetricReporterFactory` with the contents `org.apache.flink.metrics.kafka.KafkaReporterFactory` in `/resources/META-INF/services/`.